# O que significa este trecho de código?

Tags: java, swing

Recentemente me deparei com uma pedra no sapato, estava eu indo comentar um código, mas percebi que estava enchendo linguiça ao comenta-lo, pois não sei qual é o real uso do código abaixo:

```
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();
lblResolucao.setText(+d.width +" x " +d.height);
```

No caso é um código em Swing para capturar a resolução do dispositivo, mas eu não faço ideia do real motivo delas estarem ali (é meio confuso até para explicar).

Gostaria que vocês me explicassem as 2 primeiras linhas DETALHADAMENTE para que eu possa assim, realmente entender o código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leitura que se faz do código:

Na linha `Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();` você faz uso do *método estático* `getDefaultToolkit()` para retornar o `Toolkit` específico da plataforma, sendo Toolkit uma superclasse de todas as atuais implementações de `Abstract Window Toolkit(AWT)`, e salva na referência `tk`, do tipo `Toolkit`.

Na linha `Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();` você acessa o método `getScreenSize()` do seu objeto `tk`, que retorna um objeto do tipo `Dimension`, que encapsula os valores `width` e `height` com a largura e altura da tela.

```
/*
 * Output:
Screen width = 1280
Screen height = 1024
 */

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension d = tk.getScreenSize();
    System.out.println("Screen width = " + d.width);
    System.out.println("Screen height = " + d.height);

  }
}
```

Comment: AWT não é uma classe.

Comment: Certo. Vou corrigir. Esse erro foi uma tradução errada e equivocada do trecho "This class is the abstract superclass of all actual implementations of the Abstract Window Toolkit. Subclasses of the Toolkit class are used to bind the various components to particular native toolkit implementations. " da documentação da classe Toolkit.

Comment: Outra coisa, o que with e height encapsula? Ficou muito vago isso.

Comment: Corrigido. Encapsula valores de largura e altura da tela.

Answer (score 3):

A `Toolkit` é uma super classe que contém diversas informações sobre os mais diversos tipos de janelas e frames em Java. Entenda como se ela contivesse diversas informações brutas sobre as janelas, como não é aconselhado acessar estas informações diretamente você utiliza outras classes para obter as informações refinadas desta primeira.

No seu caso você usa a classe `Dimension` para obter informações de dimensão da janela do seu dispositivo. Para mais informações acesse a documentação da classe `Toolkit`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html